# th:field is breaking checked method in HTML input field

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a basic HTML post form like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" th:field="*{type}" th:value="'Flight'" name="flight" id="flight" checked>
        <label for="flight" th:text="'Flight'"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" th:field="*{type}" th:value="'Bus'" name="bus" id="bus">
        <label for="bus" th:text="'Bus'"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" th:field="*{type}" th:value="'Personal'" name="personal" id="personal">
        <label for="personal" th:text="'Personal'"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to take input from radio buttons but `checked` method is not working:

[image]

But when I remove the `th:field` method, it works fine:

[image]

What am I doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `th:field` overwrites the checked attribute. To get a default radio to be checked there are 2 solutions I believe.

1. pre-fill your `th:object` bean with the default value. When this is the case `th:field` should automatically check the correct radio.
2. Use javascript to check the radio button after rendering

P.S. when setting static string as value you can just use `value="Bus"` no need to write `th:value="'Bus'"`

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved it with the 1st solution you just mentioned! Don't I need to use all methods as a thymeleaf? Like th:value instead of value?

Comment: No thymeleaf is an extension on html, it doesnt replace it. For example in your html your overriding the name on your radio buttons that `th:field` would've set by manualy defining them (they might be incorrect though as they wil be posted as such to the controller)

Comment: Thank you so much! In this case, I can remove 'checked' method too right? Because its already does not helping.

Comment: Yes you can, `th:field` does id, name, value, checked, selected automatically

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a valid solution but:

```
private String type = "Flight";
```

setting my `type = "Flight"` in my controller solved it.

Comment: It is the correct solution.